# Why is incrementing a number in 10 Java threads not resulting in a value of 10?

Tags: java, concurrency

I don't understand the value of 'a' is 0,Why is 'a' not 10,What is the running process of that code,Is it necessary to analyze from Java Memory Model? Here is my test code

```java
package com.study.concurrent.demo;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

//@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
class DemoApplicationTests {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
//        final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executorService.execute(() -> {
//                try {
//                    semaphore.acquire();
//                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
                add();
                bdd();
//              log.info("a: {},concurrent_id: {}",a,Thread.currentThread().getName());
//                semaphore.release();
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        log.info("The final value of a：{}",a);
        log.info("The final value of b：{}",b);
    }


    public void add(){
        a++;
    }
    public void bdd(){
        b++;
    }

}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should (almost) always release the `semaphore` in a `finally` block, to make sure you don't accidentally forget to release it.

Comment: Try using `submit()` instead of `execute()`.  Submit returns a `Future` that allows you to wait for the thread to finish (or can even just get a value returned by the thread).

Comment: @markspace another reason to use `submit` to submit a `Callable` (as alluded to in the last sentence) is that `Callable`s allow checked exceptions to be thrown, so you don't have to worry about handling the `InterruptedException` explicitly.

Comment: @developYan, there are visibility, atomicity and happens-before issues in the code. I have added an answer to handle all these 3 conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, even if they are not adopted, . Your answers have relieved my confusion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You're not waiting for the threads to finish, you're just shutting down the thread pool (that is: causing the thread pool to reject new tasks but continue to process existing tasks).
2. You're not establishing a happens-before relationship between the writes in the thread pool and the read in the main thread.

   You could do this by (amongst other methods):

   1. Acquiring the semaphore before reading `a`;
   2. By using `submit` instead of `execute` to get a `Future<?>` for each of the tasks submitted, and invoking the `Future.get()` method on all of the returned futures. It is documented in [the Javadoc of `ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that this establishes a happens-before.

The first point is the "main" reason why `a` is coming out as zero: if I run it locally, and wait for the the thread pool to terminate, `a` comes out to 10.

However, just because it comes out as 10 doesn't mean the code works correctly without paying attention to the second point: you need to apply the Java Memory Model to have guarantees of correct functioning.

Comment: there is no happens-before relationship or atomicity in the read and writes within thread pool threads. So, we may need to fix the update operation of `a` and `b` to have a predictable behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer，I've forgotten that multithreading and the main thread execute asynchronously，Multithreading is also random and the value of 'b' of 10 is not necessarily true

Answer (score 5):

### Issues

1. Visibility - Multiple threads are accessing the same variable and the code does not have any visibility guarantees
2. `volatile` can help with visibility guarantee
3. Atomicity - Multiple threads are updating through `a++` or `b++` operations. These are not atomic operations. This is primarily set of operations `1. fetch a. 2. increment a. 3. update a`. A context switch can happen in any of these states and result in incorrect value.
4. So `volatile` visibility alone is not enough for correctness
5. Use `AtomicInteger` to guarantee atomicity of the increment operation
6. `AtomicXXX` can guarantee atomicity of a single operation
7. If there was a need to increment both `a` and `b` together, then some form of synchronization is needed
8. Communication - This is not communication between the main thread and executor task threads to communicate completion events
9. `executorService.shutdown()` will not ensure this communication
10. `Latch` can be used for this communication
11. Or as mentioned by Andy, `Future` can be used

### An example code with `AtomicInteger` and `Latch`

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class DemoApplicationTests {
    final AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger(0);

    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                add();
                bdd();
                latch.countDown();
            });
        }
        latch.await();
        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("The final value of a：" + a);
        System.out.println("The final value of b：" + b);
    }

    public void add() {
        a.incrementAndGet();
    }
    public void bdd() {
        b.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new DemoApplicationTests().contextLoads();
    }
}
```

### An incorrect solution with `threadpool size > 1` and `CompletableFuture` due to race conditions in `a++`, `b++`.

The following can(my knowledge is limited and can't confirm either way) be a perfectly legal code for a thread pool size of `1` (copied from [Eugene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105755/on-java-concurrency/66105908#66105908))

But when the same code was executed with thread pool size > `1`, it will result in race conditions. (again the intention is to discuss about multiple threads and data visibility issues as is and not to project Eugene's answer as incorrect. Eugene's answer is in the context of single thread in threadpool and might be perfectly valid for single threaded threadpool scenario)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class DemoApplicationTests {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        final int count = 10000;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Runnable r = () -> {
                add();
                bdd();
            };
            list.add(r);
        }

        CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = list.stream()
            .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, executorService))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();

        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("The final value of a: " + a);
        System.out.println("The final value of b：" + b);
    }

    public void add() {
        a++;
    }
    public void bdd() {
        b++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new DemoApplicationTests().contextLoads();
    }
}
```

Thank you @Basil Bourque for fixing the grammatical errors

Comment: your example with `AtomicInteger` is correct, but why do you  need a `CountDownLatch` there?

Comment: @Eugene, as my code did not use Futures to communicate between the tasks and main thread, i used the CountDownLatch. The primary advantage(just a personal understanding and could be wrong) is: If only a portion of every task (say initial fast in-memory operation followed by slow IO) is required by other part of a program, then i thought `CountDownLatch` might be a useful construct to coordinate. Otherwise, the user has to break these code in further granular tasks (separate set of tasks for in-memory and IO to speed up other waiting part of execution. but this might complicate data sharing).

Comment: @Eugene, on different note from the above comment, even removing the `executorService.shutdown();` would still result in correct count printed for `a` and `b`. (as the main thread in the example relies only on the state of these 2 values). Atomicity and visibility is controlled by `AtomicInteger` and wait/notify is handled by `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: but `AtomicInteger` already offers visibility and atomicity. If you want to see `10` as the result, always, `CountDownLatch` is not needed here.

Comment: @Eugene, With the code as it is, `CountDownLatch` is used to communicate the completion of the executor tasks to main thread.

Comment: @Eugene, My previous comment also states this: `Atomicity and visibility is controlled by AtomicInteger and wait/notify is handled by CountDownLatch.`

Comment: you're right. I missed that there is no `awaitTermination`. But this made me scratch my head a few times. Can you get atomicity, _without_ visibility? Cause right now, even if you drop the `CountDownLatch`, you will still see `10`, because `AtomicInteger::incrementAndGet` is documented to use that `VarHandle::getAndAdd` with proper volatile semantics... if it makes sense what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 4):

Your pool has `1` thread, and you submit `10` `Runnable`s to it. They will all pile-up in a `queue`, until it's their turn to execute. Instead of waiting for all of them to `finish`, you call `shutDown`, effectively saying : "no more tasks will this pool take". When exactly is that going to happen and how many tasks have already been processed before the call to `shutDown` happened, is impossible to tell. As such, you get a very non-deterministic result. You could even see `10` as the output (sometimes), but that does not mean this is correct.

Instead, you can wait for the pool to finish executing all of its tasks:

```
executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executorService.shutdown();
```

What slightly "sucks" is that `awaitTermination` does not explicitly mentions that if it returns `true`, it would establish a `happens-before` relationship. So to be pedantic with the `JLS`, you would need to work with that `Semaphore` for example, to establish the needed guarantees.

---

You have a *race* in your code, by updating a *shared* `a` and `b` from multiple threads (even if you currently use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`), without any synchronization. So that needs correction also. And a `Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3);` is not going to help, since you still will allow `3` concurrent threads to work on those variables; you would need only a single `permit`. But then, this acts as `Lock` more then a `Semaphore`.

Comment: As per the question, there are visibility issues in `a` and `b` across threads to deterministically increment the values.

Comment: Even with this change, we may not guarantee `10` as output. We need to handle `a++` and `b++` atomically and with happens-before

Comment: @Horse and your reasonings are based on exactly what?

Comment: as per OP `I don't understand the value of 'a' is 0,Why is 'a' not 10`, the expectation is to get `10` as the computed value. This operation ```public void add(){
        a++;
    }```  does not guarantee visibility to same value across threads and also does not guarantee atomic increment of values. As per your current change, we can wait for completion of all tasks before accessing `a` or `b`, but how are we guaranteeing the atomic increments of properly sequenced access to the values? I might be incorrect, but this is my understanding.

Comment: Irrespective of the number of threads (in this case only `2` - 1. main thread and 2. task thread), is there a guarantee to the freshness when these threads are scheduled by thread pool(even sequentially due to size 1) across multiple cores based on a previous copy of a value? Maybe atomicity can be fine as there is only 1 thread accessing the value at any given time(due to thread pool size - `1`).

Comment: @Horse you' re right. I was so caught up in understanding if `CompletableFuture::join` would provide the needed _visibility_ guarantees, that I missed the obvious. thank you for the heads-up here.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to share the update.

Answer (score 3):

The other Answers are correct, with important points. In addition, let me show how future technology being developed in Project Loom will simplify such code.

## Project Loom

[Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) will be bringing some changes to Java. Experimental builds of Loom technology, based on early-access [Java 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_17), are [available now](http://jdk.java.net/loom/). The Loom team is soliciting feedback.

### `AutoCloseable` and try-with-resources

One change is that `ExecutorService` extends [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). This means we can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to conveniently and automatically close the service after the try-block completes.

### Block until submitted tasks are done

Furthermore, the flow-of-control blocks on that try-block until all the submitted tasks are done/failed/canceled. No need to track progress of the individual tasks, unless you care to.

```java
try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
)
{
    … submit tasks to the executor service, to be run on background threads.
}
// At this point, all submitted are done/failed/canceled. 
// At this point, the executor service is automatically being shut down.
```

### `AtomicInteger`

As others said, your use of `int` primitives for `a` &  `b` variables across threads may fail because of visibility issues in the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model). One option is to mark them as `volatile`.

I prefer the alternative, using the `Atomic…` classes. Replace those `int` vars with [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) objects to wrap the incrementing count number.

Mark those member fields `final` so each instance is never replaced.

```java
// Member fields
final AtomicInteger a, b;

// Constructor
public Incrementor ( )
{
    this.a = new AtomicInteger();
    this.b = new AtomicInteger();
}
```

To increment by one the value within the `AtomicInteger`, we call [`incrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet()). This call returns the new incremented number. So I altered the signature of your add methods to show that we can return the new value, if ever needed.

```java
// Logic
public int addA ( )
{
    return this.a.incrementAndGet();
}

public int addB ( )
{
    return this.b.incrementAndGet();
}
```

### Virtual threads

Another feature coming in Project Loom is *virtual threads*, also known as *fibers*. Many of these lightweight threads are mapped to run on platform/kernel threads. If your code often blocks, then using virtual threads will dramatically speed up performance of your app. Use the new feature by calling [`Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadExecutor()).

```java
try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
)
{ … }
```

### Example class

I have written a class named `Incrementor` to be similar to yours. Using such a class looks like this:

```java
        Incrementor incrementor = new Incrementor();
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
            {
                executorService.submit( ( ) -> {
                    int newValueA = incrementor.addA();
                    int newValueB = incrementor.addB();
                    System.out.println( "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " incremented a & b to: " + newValueA + " & " + newValueB + " at " + Instant.now() );
                } );
            }
        }
```

#### Coordinating `a` & `b`

Caveat: As others commented, such code does not atomically increment both `a` & `b` together in synch. Apparently that is not a need of yours, so I ignore the issue. You can see that behavior in action, in the example run output shown at bottom below, where two threads interleaved during their access to `a` & `b`. Excerpted here:

```
Thread 24 incremented a & b to: 10 & 9 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.270246Z
Thread 23 incremented a & b to: 9 & 10 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.270246Z
```

#### Full class code

Pull together all this code.

Notice the simplicity of the code when (a) under Loom, and (b) using `Atomic…` constants. No need for semaphores, latches, `CompletableFuture`, nor calling `ExecutorService#shutdown`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Incrementor
{
    // Member fields
    final AtomicInteger a , b ;

    // Constructor
    public Incrementor ( )
    {
        this.a = new AtomicInteger();
        this.b = new AtomicInteger();
    }

    // Logic
    public int addA ( )
    {
        return this.a.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int addB ( )
    {
        return this.b.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

And a `main` method to demonstrate using that class.

```java
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // Exercise this class by instantiating, then incrementing ten times.
        System.out.println( "INFO - `main` starting the demo. " + Instant.now() );

        Incrementor incrementor = new Incrementor();
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
            {
                executorService.submit( ( ) -> {
                    int newValueA = incrementor.addA();
                    int newValueB = incrementor.addB();
                    System.out.println( "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " incremented a & b to: " + newValueA + " & " + newValueB + " at " + Instant.now() );
                } );
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "INFO - At this point all submitted tasks are done/failed/canceled, and executor service is shutting down. " + Instant.now() );
        System.out.println( "incrementor.a.get() = " + incrementor.a.get() );
        System.out.println( "incrementor.b.get() = " + incrementor.b.get() );
        System.out.println( "INFO - `main` ending. " + Instant.now() );
    }
```

When run.

```
INFO - `main` starting the demo. 2021-02-09T02:21:30.173816Z
Thread 18 incremented a & b to: 4 & 4 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.245812Z
Thread 14 incremented a & b to: 1 & 1 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.242306Z
Thread 20 incremented a & b to: 6 & 6 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.246784Z
Thread 21 incremented a & b to: 8 & 8 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.269666Z
Thread 22 incremented a & b to: 7 & 7 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.269666Z
Thread 17 incremented a & b to: 3 & 3 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.243580Z
Thread 24 incremented a & b to: 10 & 9 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.270246Z
Thread 23 incremented a & b to: 9 & 10 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.270246Z
Thread 16 incremented a & b to: 2 & 2 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.242335Z
Thread 19 incremented a & b to: 5 & 5 at 2021-02-09T02:21:30.246646Z
INFO - At this point all submitted tasks are done/failed/canceled, and executor service is shutting down. 2021-02-09T02:21:30.279542Z
incrementor.a.get() = 10
incrementor.b.get() = 10
INFO - `main` ending. 2021-02-09T02:21:30.285862Z
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding about Project Loom. I have downloaded based on your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your generous answer. It's very detailed

Comment: @Horse I highly recommend the videos by Ron Pressler if you are trying Loom. See the more recent ones of 2020. Things have changed since the initial debut of Project Loom, such as no longer using `Fiber` as a class name.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Sure. Thanks again for sharing the information.

Comment: do not think that loom is panacea, not yet, at least. they have (big?) issues with ThreadLocals, at least. Which _partially_ works with `G1GC`, and in a "weird" way, at the moment. as far as I see it, it is far from reality yet.

Comment: @Eugene Agreed. Thus my use of the word "experimental". As the dictionary says: *(of a new invention or product) based on untested ideas or techniques and not yet established or finalized*